# QtQuick 2 Blur Effect Background

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a **semi-transparent** window and **I'm trying to apply a blur effect on the background.**
I tried FastBlur from QtGraphicalEffects on my root element(Rectangle) but it doesn't seem to work.

The qml file is loaded into a QQuickVIew from my main c++ file.

I'm using the method of my answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554796/qtquick-2-transparent-window-background) for making my window transparent.

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894244/qml-and-blurring-image)?

Comment: Yes I have tried it with no luck.

Comment: I think blurring an item with a single color doesn't do anything, Qt doesn't detect the background if you make it transparent or anything. The blur effect is just applied to the colors of the item, and if they are all the same color nothing happens obliviously. if you want to blur the pixels behind your window that's a bit tricky i guess, you can maybe capture the image or something but this is not part of your app so I don't know how do to that easily.